# How to read/convert arc000dat files?

Tags: convert, arcinfo-workstation

I have a number of files that I am trying to import, but I'm just failing at the first hurdle.

I've got a directory structure and file list that looks like this:

```
 Directory of C:\blah

01/04/2011  14:41    <DIR>          info
01/04/2011  17:01               951 log
01/04/2011  14:41    <DIR>          mastertic
01/04/2011  14:41    <DIR>          site
01/04/2011  14:41    <DIR>          street
01/04/2011  17:01               575 verify.wat
               2 File(s)          1,526 bytes

 Directory of C:\blah\info

01/04/2011  14:41    <DIR>          .
01/04/2011  14:41    <DIR>          ..
01/04/2011  17:01                80 arc000dat
01/04/2011  17:01               432 arc000nit
01/04/2011  17:01                80 arc001dat
01/04/2011  17:01               576 arc001nit
01/04/2011  17:01                80 arc002dat
01/04/2011  17:01               432 arc002nit
01/04/2011  17:01                80 arc003dat
01/04/2011  17:01             1,008 arc003nit
01/04/2011  17:01                80 arc004dat
01/04/2011  17:01               576 arc004nit
01/04/2011  17:01                80 arc005dat
01/04/2011  17:01               864 arc005nit
01/04/2011  17:01                80 arc006dat
01/04/2011  17:01               576 arc006nit
01/04/2011  17:01                80 arc007dat
01/04/2011  17:01             1,728 arc007nit
01/04/2011  17:01                80 arc008dat
01/04/2011  17:01               432 arc008nit
01/04/2011  17:01             3,420 arcdr9
01/04/2011  17:01                 0 arcnsp
              20 File(s)         10,764 bytes

 Directory of C:\blah\mastertic

01/04/2011  14:41    <DIR>          .
01/04/2011  14:41    <DIR>          ..
01/04/2011  17:01                32 dblbnd
01/04/2011  17:01                80 dbltic
01/04/2011  17:01               169 log
               3 File(s)            281 bytes

 Directory of C:\blah\site

01/04/2011  14:41    <DIR>          .
01/04/2011  14:41    <DIR>          ..
01/04/2011  17:01            17,732 arc
01/04/2011  17:01               780 arx
01/04/2011  17:01             1,504 cnt
01/04/2011  17:01               452 cnx
01/04/2011  17:01                32 dblbnd
01/04/2011  17:01                80 dbltic
01/04/2011  17:01             2,508 lab
01/04/2011  17:01             1,024 log
01/04/2011  17:01             4,424 pal
01/04/2011  17:01               260 par
01/04/2011  17:01             1,496 pat
01/04/2011  17:01               452 pax
              12 File(s)         30,744 bytes

 Directory of C:\blah\street

01/04/2011  14:41    <DIR>          .
01/04/2011  14:41    <DIR>          ..
01/04/2011  17:01             1,288 aat
01/04/2011  17:01             9,268 arc
01/04/2011  17:01               324 arx
01/04/2011  17:01                32 dblbnd
01/04/2011  17:01                80 dbltic
01/04/2011  17:01           352,802 log
01/04/2011  17:01             1,330 nat
01/04/2011  17:01               260 par
               8 File(s)        365,384 bytes
```

There are no file extensions, but from googling, it suggests that you could convert these using Arc Workstation?  Does anybody know if there is another way of loading or converting these files?

I have an ArcGIS 10 desktop licence, and a variety of open source tools at my disposal!

Answer (score 3):

In ArcGIS (any licence level)

**Import from E00 (Conversion)  [in To Coverage ToolSet]**

*"Imports an ArcInfo interchange file (.e00). An interchange file is used to transport coverages, INFO tables, text files such as AML macros, and other ArcInfo files. For coverages, grids, and tins, it contains all information, including appropriate INFO table information. Interchange files are designated with the .e00 file suffix. This is the ArcView 3.x version of the utility for importing .e00 files. "*

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000046000000

Comment: Thanks for replying.  But I don't have any files with an E00 extension?

Answer (score 3):

ArcInfo Workstation includes a CONVERTWORKSPACE command that will convert a workspace from pre-7 format to the 7.0 format readable by current versions of ArcGIS.

It's a good thing ogr2ogr can do this too!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have three [coverage](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=How_coverages_are_stored) files, mastertic, site, and street.  You should be able to load these files using the Add Data button in arcmap.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Add Data button doesn't work.  I can see the coverages listed in ArcCatalog - they are marked as Pre 7.0 coverage files.  But I can't seem to do anything else with them.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert those coverage files to shape files using the [Feature Class to Shapefile tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000020000000).

> Converts a shapefile, coverage feature class, or geodatabase feature
>   class to a shapefile or geodatabase feature class.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for OGR indicates ogr2ogr will read Pre version 7 ArcInfo Coverage data. So, you should be able to convert the vector data to Shapefile or other usable format. Another option is using AVCexport, to convert each coverage to an E00 (export file). Then ArcGIS might be able to import each e00.  Also, the TatukGIS Viewer should allow you to view the native arcinfo coverage.